# Synology Diskstation Local Backup Does Not Overwrite Changed Files

Tags: synology

I have a problem regarding local backups with my diskstation. I have a separate maschine that provides a shared drive. The DISKSTATION has included this shared drive and can read and write to it. So far so good. Now I have created a local backup plan to backup the contents of this shared drive to a separate folder at the diskstation. This works very well and the backup successfully copied all files from the shared folder to a local folder/drive. However, when the second run of the backup process starts changed files won't get copied. New files however get copied. I tried it with preserve and without the preserve option but the result is the same. Initial backup works, following backups only works with new files, changed files won't get touched.

**system information**

Diskstation: DS409
DMS Version: DSM 4.2-3255 (latest available)

**steps to reproduce**

1. Create a shared folder on a separate maschine
2. Include the shared drive to the diskstation, providing credentials
3. create a backup plan with source -> shared drive, target -> local folder
4. run the backup (all contents get successfully copied to local folder)
5. change a file on the remote maschine
6. add a file to the remote maschine
7. run backup again (only the new created file is now at the local folder)

**update**

changed the question body to make my problem more clear, added steps I took

Comment: _"I do NOT want that the remote system backups TO the Diskstation, I want the Diskstation to GET the contents from the remote system."_ - your description is a bit confusing.  Are you trying to backup some drive on your network?

Comment: Yes, a maschine in the network provides a shared drive. I want the diskstations to backup the contents of the drive but I don't want the remote maschine "know" about the diskstation. I mean the remote maschine has no access to read or write files to/from the diskstation. The backup works, thats not the problem, the problem is, that changed files won't get backed up in the second run. Only new files will get backed up in the second run. I would be happy if at least changed files would overwrite. More happy if they would get saved incremental

Comment: @rrirower I rewrote the question, maybe it is more clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer from Synology support that told me, that the file protocol does not support that scenario and that I have to switch the setup around and **push** the files **to the backup** diskstation instead of getting them.